# Resetting state of react-select component not working

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am having two problems with my react-select component:

1st: when I select and option, I am not able to change the option after I set the select component
2nd: when my form resets, it does not reset the react-select component.

**For practical reasons, this is just pertaining the issue itself so I left of other input fields on purpose and to keep this short as much as possible**

Below is a sample of what I am working with. I used a async request to grab my options from a api, and the good news is the option populate. The issue I am having is once I pick a option I cannot change it, and when I submit the form, all the other fields and not the select component reset. I have to reload the page for the  component to reset. What can I do to correct this?

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import Select from 'react-select'
import axios from 'axios'
import '../index.css'



class RecipeInput extends Component{

   
    constructor(props){
        super(props)
        this.state = {
            category_id:'',
            name:'',
            ingredients:'',
            chef_name:'',
            origin:'',
            instructions:'',
            
         }
        
}


      

    
    async options(){
        const BASE_URL = `http://localhost:3002`
        const CATEGORIES_URL =`${BASE_URL}/categories`
        const res = await axios.get(CATEGORIES_URL)
        const data = res.data

        const options = data.map(options => ({
            'label' : options.category,
            'id' : options.id
        }))

        this.setState({category_id: options})
    }



    
     handleSelect = (event) =>{
        
        this.setState({category_id:event.id})
    }

    componentDidMount(){
        this.options()
    }


    handleReset = () =>{
        this.setState({ name:'', ingredients: '', chef_name: '', origin: '',instructions: '', category_id:''})
    }

   

    handleSubmit = (event) =>{
        event.preventDefault();
        this.props.postRecipes(this.state)
        this.handleReset()
              
    }

    

    render(){
       let dropdown = 'form-select form-select-sm'
        return(
            <div>
                
                <form onSubmit={(event)=>this.handleSubmit(event)} noValidate>
                    <Select  options={this.state.category_id} value={this.state.category_id} onChange={(event)=>this.handleSelect(event)} className={dropdown}/>
                   
                    <input value='submit' type='submit' />
                </form>
                
            </div>
        )
    }

}

export default RecipeInput
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you are using same category_id state variable for both options array and value prop on select element.
You need to provide options array to option property
And category_id state variable that will be changing to value property.

Comment: So I figured that I needed to grab the options array but for some reason I have buried within my async function, so I am running into a scope issue

Answer (score 0):

So there was one little detail that I don't anyone caught. Well one I remembered was when you submit a form with a part of it making a asynchronous request within it, the component unmounts and you have to mount it again when you reset the form.

Here is me making my async call to the api

```
async options(){
        const BASE_URL = `http://localhost:3002`
        const CATEGORIES_URL =`${BASE_URL}/categories`
        const res = await axios.get(CATEGORIES_URL)
        const data = res.data

        const options = data.map(options => ({
            'label' : options.category,
            'id' : options.id
        }))

        this.setState({category_id: options})
    }
```

And here is where the component mounts when the page is loaded.

```
 componentDidMount(){
        this.options()
    }
```

Well when you submit the form the line above basically unmounts and I was not remounting it on form reset.

Here is the solution that resolved it.

```
handleReset = () =>{
        this.setState({ name:'', ingredients: '', chef_name: '', origin: '',instructions: '',category_id:''})
    }

   

    handleSubmit = (event) =>{
        event.preventDefault();
        this.props.postRecipes(this.state)
        this.handleReset()
        this.getOptions()
              
    }
```

You'll notice above I simply remounted **this.getOptions()** when I interacted with the submit button.